# Torah Study Of Rabbinic Laws

Tags: torah-study, derabanan, deorayta

Does one fulfill the Biblical precept to study Torah while studying Rabbinic precepts? R. Mordechai of Vilna writes that one does not.  Are there disputants?  Please answer with exact sources or powerful inferences.

Comment: To which "R. Mordechai of Vilna" do you refer, and where did you hear this?

Comment: I've never heard of R. Mordechai of Vilna. Who is he?

Comment: I think the author of maasa rav on the Gaon, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Fred this idea from r moredechai of vilna is brought in the back of the siddur hagr"a "Eizur Eliyahu" just before a copy of maaseh rav. His conclusion is based off the famous gemara in megilla that "mevatlin talmud torah lemikra megillah" he asks how could it be a bittul torah, isnt megillah also torah? he answers that it is only talmud torah miderabanan.

Comment: Thats where I saw it.  It happens to be that the proof is predicated upon an understanding of the Gemara contrary to Ritva there.

Comment: @mevaqesh No, the author of Maaseh Rav was R. Yissachar Ber [*dayan*] of Vilna; his son who was charged with printing the book was Mordechai.

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv Would you kindly give the page number in EE? Having difficulty locating it in my copy.

Comment: @Oliver definitely I'll try after Shabbos to get it for you. You can also email me at mefaresh@gmail.com and I can send you a picture of the mareh makom. Good Shabbos!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two sources I know of indicating that one does **not** fulfill the mitzvah of Talmud Torah by learning laws which are *derabanan*:

1. There is a law that one may not receive payment for teaching Torah, but the Rama (Y.D. 246:5) writes that this is not true regarding teaching of rabbinic laws. This strongly implies that there's no biblical obligation to study these laws.

   - The Aruch Hashulchan (there) writes that he finds this ruling difficult, as the Gemara (Megillah 19, Brachos 5a) indicates that even the rabbinic laws were told to Moshe at Sinai
   - **R. Ahron Leib Shteinman**, (Ayeles Hashachar to Nedarim 37a) writes that although this halacha indicates that studying rabbinic laws such as eiruvin or channukah wouldn't fulfill the mitzvah of Talmud Torah, he writes that this is not the case. Perhaps the mitzvah really is fulfilled, but the rule of teaching Torah without pay doesn't apply because Moshe himself never 'taught' these laws.
2. According to Talmidei Rabbeinu Yonah (Brachos 11b), one only makes a bracha on studying Talmud or the like because it is an explanation of the Written Torah. (Based on this, the Aruch Hashulchan (47:8) is hesitant to make a bracha on studying *aggados*, because they do not explain any scriptural verses.)

   - It would appear, therefore, that studying laws which do not explain scripture (such as the laws of Chanukah) are not subject to *birkas haTorah*, probably because Rabbeinu Yonah felt that such study cannot be considered *talmud Torah d'oraisa*
   - However, the Eshel Avraham (47:2) writes based on the Rambam that one does make a bracha on studying purely rabbinic laws as well (could this be a dispute between Rambam and Rabbeinu Yonah?)

Besides for R. Shteinman, here are the words of R. Soloveitchik as recorded in שעירוים לזכר אבא מרי ז"ל, pg 253:

> האם נאמר למשל כי מכיון שמצות מגילה היא רק מד"ס גם הלכות מגילה אינן מוטבעות בחותמה של תורה שבע"פ דבר תורה ומסכת מגילה מהווה חפצא של תורה רק מדבריהם שמדאורייתא אין בה חלות תורה כלל וכלל... שהלומד אותה אינו מקיים מצות תלמוד תורה מדאורייתא כי הלא כל הדברים שמסכת זו עסוקה בהם אינם אלא רשות דבר תורה? ...נראה פשוט כי התפיסה השניה נכונה וכי כל דיני מצוות דרבנן חפצא של תורה הויין ואין שום הבדל ביניהם לבין הלכות מילה או חמש הלכות שחיטה

Rav Soloveitchik then shows how this is evident from the Rambam (Hil. Mamrim 1) who includes the laws made by the rabbis as *התורה אשר יורוך*.

Building on this principle, **Rabbi Zvi/Hershel Schachter** writes in Nefesh Harav (pg. 41) that these laws become an integral part of the Torah itself, and therefore studying them is very much a fulfillment of the Biblical command. He relates this to the rule that כל דתקון רבנן כעין דאורייתא תקון, the rabbis pattern their enactments similar to the ways of the Torah, because it's all one inter-related package. In person, I've heard him take this a step further: there are times when one can understand a biblical law better because we can extrapolate from a detail in a rabbinic law which was patterned after the biblical one (he pointed to Kovetz he'Aros of R. Elchanan Wasserman, no. 66 for examples). We therefore see that even rabbinic enactments can indirectly clarify scriptural verses, perhaps answering the problem posed by the implication from Rabbeinu Yonah above.

Comment: +1, but I think you meant "two indications that the answer is yes".

Comment: @Fred I meant no (as an answer to "Does one fulfill the Biblical precept to study Torah while studying Rabbinic precepts?") as the indications are towards 'no', but honestly the information here is very poorly organized/presented, I may come back and rework it later

Comment: Well, it looks to me like 2 and 3 indicate "yes", while 1 is open to different interpretations.

Comment: @Fred I am definitely going to rewrite this later

Comment: I believe I've heard that Rav Michael Rosensweig of RIETS/YU in a Q&A answered that he would make birchas hatorah even on reading outdated medical advice of Chazal (though I wonder if his answer was somewhat polemical in nature due to perceived agendas in the question and the public nature of the forum).

Comment: @loewian I'm sure that he didn't really mean that, but I obviously can't know for sure. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50550/5083

Answer (score 2):

Shulchan Aruch HaRav writes in Hilchos Talmud Torah ([2:1](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/2/1)) that the obligation to study Torah includes דיקדוקי סופרים, which Rashi ([Succah 28a](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/2/1)) defines as Rabbinic enactments.

(Note that, pace the Aruch Hashulchan, he paskens ([O.C. 47:2](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/47/2)) that Birchas HaTorah applies to Medrash as well).

Comment: How do you know he is using Rashi's definition?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it seems kind of obvious, and the author of the footnotes (forget who he is offhand) agrees.

Comment: The footnotes were a [collaborative effort](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=).

Answer (score 0):

Additional evidence that one doesn't fulfill a biblical obligation can be adduced from Rambam's opinion that one is obligated to teach his son specifically the written law (Hil. Talmud Torah 1:7). In general Rambam (e.g. sefer hamitzvos assei 11) parallels the obligations of personal study and teaching ones sons as parts of the commandment "v'shinantem l'vanecha" as noted by Maharam Shik (cited in sefer hamafteach to talmud torah 1:7). This would imply that one's personal biblical obligation to study also includes only the written law.

Maharam Shik himself however assumes that the obligation to teach students, and presumably one's personal obligation **does** include the oral law, and therefore doesn't understand Rambam's ruling about teaching specifically the written law.

Comment: So gemara doesn't count? That's sounds pretty extreme.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rambam seems to adopt the interesting approach (not that I know any Rishonim who disagree) that one ought to spend one's time of study (two thirds in the beginning, more later) on subjects outside the purview of the commandment to study torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA why is this not a question on R. Yona, et al quoted above?

Comment: It sounds like R Yona would be ok with parts of gemara which deal even indirectly with pesukim, ie all deoraysas. Is that what you think the rambam here means?

Comment: Rambam Hilcohs Talmud Torah 1:7 (8-10 in Mechon Mamre) is crystal clear that the obligation to teach one's son includes Oral Torah, even if he has to pay for it, and that it is a personal obligation is in 1:10 (1:13 in Mechon Mamre) as well.

Comment: @Yishai i'm not seeing how the Rambam is crystal clear. In terms of teaching he only uses the term חייב about the written law. He merely discusses the **permissibility** of payment for teaching the oral law, not the obligation to do so. He does cite a verse in Mishlei to show that one may pay for the oral law, but the context is whether it is permissible, not whether it is obligatory. Furthermore, even his point is to say that one should, that doesnt mean that it is a kiyum of T"T; just of the passuk in Mishlei. Furthermore, the Maharam Shik understood like me not like you. to be continued.

Comment: @Yishai furthermore, Rambam in 1:10 just says that if one doesn't study he will forget. Perhaps you meant 1:11 where he says that one should divide his study into various categories. How do you see that all of these are the fulfillment of the biblical command to study Torah?

Comment: @mevaqesh,   לא מצא מי שילמדו בחינם--ילמוד בשכר. Could not be clearer. If you can't find for free, you have to pay. Re 1:11 (yes, my mistake) וחייב לשלש את זמן למידתו.  He is telling you how you have to fulfill the mitzva, not adding some additional rabbinic requirement.

Comment: @Yishai Rambam segued from talking about teaching your son to paying for Torah. He is no longer discussing v'shinantam l'vanecha, but a seperate matter entirely. ילמוד בשכר literally means he will learn. In mishnaic hebrew this means he should. The primary context however is just that it is permitted. Even though the language implies that one should this doesnt mean it is an obligation of v'shinantam 'vanecha. It might just be a good idea as his citation of Mishlei implies. I agree that the Rambam isnt super clear, but this seems to be the pashtus and it is the understanding of Maharam Shik.

Comment: @Yishai BTW even if he were telling you a rabbinic requirement it wouldn't be a proof that the oral law is included in v'shinantam l'vanecha.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I was looking into this a bit, and it is a whole sugia. Let's just say that the Maharam Shik is a very minority opinion in how to understand the Rambam. But I stand by the fact that the Rambam is crystal clear. Consider also  וחייב לשכור מלמד לבנו ללמדו followed by מי שלא לימדו אביו--חייב ללמד את עצמו כשיכיר and then וכן אתה מוצא בכל מקום, שהתלמוד קודם למעשה, מפני שהתלמוד מביא לידי מעשה. You cannot say about learning Torah SheBeksav alone that התלמוד מביא לידי מעשה.

Comment: @Yishai to say the Rambam is crystal clear is to say the Maharam Shik doesnt know how to learn. More likely (no offense) you dont know how to learn. That is, even if you are right the Maharam Shik shows us the the matter cant be crystal clear. I think I also demonstrsated this nicely through diyukim. I thought of the diyuk of meivi lidei maasa also. There are two possible answers: a) that the mitva of v'shinantam is prioritized by Hashem because it is the only way to reach maasa, even though not every case leads to maasa. b) that this talmud torah is not included in vshinantam lvanecha.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I wouldn't be insulted at all to be compared to the Maharam Shik and say that I can't learn in comparison. Just to be put in the same paragraph is an honor. But fortunately, I'm not saying my own, just agreeing with others who are בר פלוגתא. But if you read it in the Mechon Mamre [version](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1301.htm) you may see why I say it is so clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20965/discussion-between-mevaqesh-and-yishai).