# Is it preferable to learn torah related to biblical obligations over learning torah related to rabbinic obligations?

Tags: torah-study, derabanan, deorayta

If all things are equal is there any reason to give preference to studying torah about a biblical obligation over studying torah about a rabbinic obligation? In general we give precedence to biblical obligations over rabbinic ones, I would like to know if that extends to the study of those subjects in general.

Comment: The two are intertwined in all areas of study. Practically speaking, how would you draw that distinction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Torah Study Of Rabbinic Laws](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53219/torah-study-of-rabbinic-laws)

Comment: (From the linked q&a it seems(?) Rav Soloveitchik felt they were the same: ואין שום הבדל ביניהם לבין הלכות מילה או חמש הלכות שחיטה)

Comment: @DoubleAA How is this a duplicate? That question asks if studying rabbinic laws is included in biblical talmud; this question asks if biblical study is preferable, which is a question regardless of which way that question is answered.